# Dendrograma na biblioteca factoextra

Tags: r

Criei um dendrograma no R com o pacote `factoextra` com uma coluna de variáveis numéricas, mas preciso que no final do dendrograma mostre os nomes que correspondem a cada grupo (figura abaixo).

[image: Dendrograma dos dados]

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

```r
library(factoextra)

dd <- dist(scale(dados$reducao_producao), method = "euclidean")
hc <- hclust(dd, method = "ward.D2")


fviz_dend(hc) # aqui cria o dendrograma
```

Comment: Não está claro para mim o que significa "cada grupo". Onde está essa informação? Dada a pergunta feira, sequer sabemos quantos grupos são.

Comment: Tente: `hc$labels <- dados$reducao_producao`

Comment: @MarcusNunes, obrigado por organizar minha pergunta.

Comment: @PauloMarques, consegui renomear com sua sugestão, deu muito certo! Te agradeço demais pela ajuda!!!

Answer (score 4):

Por "nomes que correspondem a cada grupo" estou assumindo que esteja se referindo ao nome de identificação de cada linha. Como não postou seus dados, vou usar um exemplo genérico:

```
set.seed(98)
dados <- data.frame(
  nomes = LETTERS[1:10],
  valores = rnorm(10))
```

Sua questão não está em `factorextra::fviz_dend`, mas em `dist`. Está passando os valores como vetor, sem nomes associados:

```
dd <- dist(dados$valores)
hc <- hclust(dd)

hc$labels
#> NULL

plot(hc)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja a ajuda para `dist`: ela espera como entrada uma matriz ou data.frame. Para identificar os elementos, precisa ter nomes de linhas atribuídos:

```
rownames(dados) <- dados$nomes

dd <- dist(dados["valores"])

plot(hclust(dd))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se por qualquer motivo não puder ou não quiser atribuir nomes de linhas, pode passar os nomes como atributo para `dd` (classe dist):

```
attr(dd, "Labels") <- dados$nomes
```

Ou diretamente para o elemento "labels" de `hc` (classe hclust):

```
hc$labels <- dados$nomes
```

Comment: Carlos Eduardo, utilizei seu exemplo aqui e funcionou perfeitamente. 
Muito obrigado pela ajuda!